# Convex hull over periodic boundary conditions

Tags: python, numpy, computational-geometry, convex-hull, boundary

I am trying to compute a convex hull, but my point set is augmented due to periodic boundary conditions. I cannot find any other work or references that have tackled this problem. The main issue is that simply computing the convex hull does not correctly represent the actual area occupied by the point set, as illustrated below in the figure.

On the left, the original point set is depicted. On the right, I have repeated the original point set as to reflect the periodic boundary conditions. In it, I have drawn potential convex hull candidates, which obviously have the same area and contain the same points but shifted.

[image: (left) the original point set, (right) the point set repeated to reflect the periodic boundary conditions]

Is there an elegant way to compute the convex hull over such boundary conditions?
More specifically, I am interested in *any* point set that falls within such a convex hull (i.e. the points within the drawn convex hulls on the right). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code to generate the plots:

```
# Initialize
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(8,4))
xax = ax[0]
yax = ax[1]

# Sample multivariate Gaussians (2D) to represent a clustered data set
N = 500 
sigma = np.diag(0.005*np.ones(2))
mu = np.array([[0.6, 0.6], [0.1,0.1], [0.95,0.05]])

# Sample with periodic boundary conditions on [0,1]^2
x = np.concatenate((
    np.random.multivariate_normal(mu[0,:], sigma, N) % 1,
    np.random.multivariate_normal(mu[1,:], sigma, N) % 1,
    np.random.multivariate_normal(mu[2,:], sigma, N) % 1
))

# Visualize the periodic boundary conditions by repeating the point set for each quadrant
quadrants = np.array([[i,j] for i in [-1,0,1] for j in [-1,0,1]])
y = x.copy()
for delta in quadrants:
    tempx = x + delta 
    y = np.concatenate((y, tempx)) if (np.sum(delta**2) != 0) else y 
    # Plot in distinct colors
    yax.plot(tempx[:,0], tempx[:,1], linestyle='none', marker='o', markersize=2)

# Plot the original point set
xax.plot(x[:,0], x[:,1], linestyle='none', marker='o', markersize=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: A rough sketch: Build a 3x3 grid of the original 2d window with 8 neighboring clones. That provides you with all point clouds in clusterable form. Apply a clustering algorithm, compute the convex hull for each cluster. Only consider clusters that not touch the window borders (all clusters / point clouds that do will have a copy elsewhere in the 3x3 grid that does not).

Comment: Yes indeed, I have a similar idea that seems to work a little bit. However, your comment to consider only those clusters that do not touch window borders helps a lot. Although I think one should only consider clusters that contain at least one point of the original dataset.

Comment: In reality, your problem is ill-posed and your grouping is somewhat arbitrary. You could as well group two clusters in the NW-SE direction, and the status of some isolated points remains unsure. In case of less dense clusters, defining a hull might just be impossible. This makes the problem more difficult. Why do you want to find this "convex hull" ?

Comment: The problem is that I wish to get the area 'spanned' by the cluster. Indeed, the problem of clustering is indeed ill-posed due to the need to introduce some arbitrary range of clustering. However, I believe that the area that the cluster occupies should not be depending on other hyperparameters right?

Therefore, in a sense, I would like to find the convex hull (across periodic boundaries) with the smallest area, and then consider that the area 'spanned' by the set of points.

Comment: @JNauta: you need to formalize this.